# Wordpress loading the_content() with the title

Tags: php, html, wordpress, function

I have a blog page, and then an individual post page for each blog post.

On my Blog page, it shows all the posts **with** their titles:

```
<div class="entry-content">
    <?php
        the_content();

        wp_link_pages( array(
        'before' => '<div class="page-links">' . __( 'Pages:', 'twentyseventeen' ),
        'after'  => '</div>',
        ) );
    ?>
</div>
```

But on the individual blog post page, it only shows the image and the blog text, not the title:

```
<div class="entry-content">
<?php
    /* translators: %s: Name of current post */
    the_content();


    wp_link_pages( array(
        'before'      => '<div class="page-links">' . __( 'Pages:', 'twentyseventeen' ),
        'after'       => '</div>',
        'link_before' => '<span class="page-number">',
        'link_after'  => '</span>',
    ) );

?>
</div>
```

How come both call `the_content()`, but it returns differently? I need to also have the title of the post show on the individual blog post page.

Comment: Please provide an example of the end result (ie. a link to a page where we can see the generated HTML).

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to add `the_title()` on your post page.

From the documentation: https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/the_title